# Subversion IE client

Tags: internet-explorer, svn, plugins, tortoisesvn

We have to use Internet Explorer at work and connections to the Internet are only allowed **through the web browser**. If there is a chance to access an external Apache Subversion Repository?

Does Subversion provide a web-interface to allow me accessing it by the Internet Explorer?

For Firefox there is a TortoiseSVN plugin, but I couldn't find anything equal tool for the Internet Explorer.

Is another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter whether you use Internet Explorer or Firefox. If you don't have a Subversion client installed on your machine, then your capabilities are limited to readonly operations such as browsing repository history.

1. Apache Subversion allows you to browse a Subversion repository with a web browser [if the repository is exposed via Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache). You can view repository contents, download files but you can't adjust versioned files or view the version history log.
2. You can install advanced web interface for your Subversion repository. E.g. WebSVN, ViewVC, etc. Such interface will extend actions you can perform against the repository using a web browser.

   If you use VisualSVN Server 3.2 or newer on the server side, then you already have [a rich interface for your repositories](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/3.2/). [**See the live demo here**](http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/).
3. If your Subversion server [is configured for autoversioning](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.webdav.html), then you can attach a remote repository as a web drive on your Windows machine. It allows you to access the remote repository as an attached drive. This way you can upload files to the repository, but it's still can't be called version-control IMO.

The bottom line is: install a Subversion client on your machine if you require more than just viewing repository history. You can't use most of Subversion's features without a client.

PS The plugin for Firefox you've mentioned is useless without TortoiseSVN client. The plugin just allows you to quickly perform TortoiseSVN actions against repository items you see in a web browser. TortoiseSVN itself must be installed for the plugin to work, i.e. Firefox does not become a Subversion client after installing the plugin.

Comment: Hi, I know about the problem. the thing is that file downloads are only allowed through IE (they are scanned for viruses automatically). So I need it to get the files through the IE standard download progress

Comment: @Niko you can download files from SVN repository via HTTP(S) if the repository is exposed via Apache HTTP Server.